# Brother HL-2270DW Network Printer Stopped Working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: printing, brother, cups-lpd

I have a Brother HL-2270DW that worked fine in Ubuntu 18.04, when I upgraded to 20.04 it stopped working. The printer can be seen on the network, and I've tried removing and adding it. Whenever I try to print a test page I get the error 'Unable to locate printer "BRN30055C1054C2.local"'.

I've tried installing the latest Brother debs including the manual steps for 64-bit architecture. I've tried setting the IP address manually. I've tried doing all this through the GUI and through localhost:631. Nothing changes the error. Please help!

Comment: Can you ping the printer using the IP address? Can you ping the printer using BRN30055C1054C2.local?